# camera2 API continuous capture with Grafika

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, grafika

Hello guys I'm trying to implement the continuous capture functionality from the Grafika library (https://github.com/google/grafika) in a custom app application but I need to use the camera2 API because I from what I learned the old camera API has been deprecated. I had a lot of problems and my code is a little bit messy because I still don't fully understand the camera2 api and the grafika implementation of the circular buffer and I will refactor everything once I manage to make it work. I hope you manage to understand where my problem lies with the given mess.
 The think I did to use the continuous capture functionality in my app is to copy all the classes in the "gles" directory in "Grafika" on which the CameraCaptureActivity depends and I also copied the CircularEncoder and CircularEncoderBuffer classes because the activity depends on them too and then I tried to recreate the things that ContinuousCaptureActivity does in my FragmentPhoneCameraNew. I haven't changed anything on any of the other classes that I copied from the "Grafika" library.
 The device on which I'm testing is samsung galaxy S6  with android 7.0.

1. My first problem is in the startPreview function when I'm trying to initialize the mCircEncoder in the try / catch block (  mCircEncoder = CircularEncoder(VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT, 6000000, mCameraPreviewThousandFps / 1000, 7, mHandler) ) where it gives me the following error :

> 07-31 11:25:40.301 25399-25533/com.name.socourt E/BufferQueueProducer:
>   [SurfaceTexture-0-25399-0] connect: already connected (cur=1 req=4)
>       07-31 11:25:40.307 25399-25533/com.name.socourt W/CameraDevice-JV-0: Stream configuration failed due to:
>   endConfigure:365: Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided
>       07-31 11:25:40.377 25399-25533/com.name.socourt E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Failed to create capture session;
>   configuration failed

2. The second problem is that after the execution passes the mEncoder.configure method in the CircularEncoder class it gives me :

> 07-31 12:11:34.866 1130-1224/com.name.socourt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: Camera background thread
>           Process: com.name.socourt, PID: 1130
>           android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0x80001001
>               at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
>               at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1882)
>               at com.name.socourt.services.CameraRelated.CircularEncoder.(CircularEncoder.java:123)
>               at com.name.socourt.controller.FragmentPhoneCameraNew.startPreview(FragmentPhoneCameraNew.kt:661)
>               at com.name.socourt.controller.FragmentPhoneCameraNew.access$startPreview(FragmentPhoneCameraNew.kt:47)
>               at com.name.socourt.controller.FragmentPhoneCameraNew$mCameraDeviceStateCallback$1.onOpened(FragmentPhoneCameraNew.kt:266)
>               at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:134)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

which I assume is because I'm doing something in the background thread that is supposed to be in the main thread or vice versa, but isn't the thread handler supposed to make the two threads communicate and prevent such problems?

I'm doing this for 2 weeks already and it's a complete mess in my head since I'm encountering such problems all the time. I manage to solve them 1 by 1 but it takes a lot of time, but this time it seems like I'm just stuck.

I'm sorry if the problems are simple or my code is too messy, but I'm new to android development and that camera 2 api is just too complicated especially when I have to implement the continuous capture functionality.

I had to upload the code and the logcat in a file to my googleDrive because it is too big to be posted as a question here in the body of the topic, I hope that is not a problem. So here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c_soL_S37ALxSoazNfEJTx9gcDs82ePG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46405261/192373) can help.