# Recording video using MediaCodec with Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, android-camera2

I am trying to use MediaCodec to record raw frames from ImageReader in onImageAvailable callback but unable to write a working code. Most of the examples are using Camera 1 API or MediaRecorder. My aim is to capture individual frames process it and create an mp4 out of it

Raw YUV frames

```
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Image i = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            processImage(i);
            i.close();
            Log.d("hehe", "onImageAvailable");
        }
    };
```

MediaCodec

```
MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(name);
 MediaFormat mOutputFormat; // member variable
 codec.setCallback(new MediaCodec.Callback() {
   @Override
   void onInputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int inputBufferId) {
     ByteBuffer inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(inputBufferId);
     // fill inputBuffer with valid data
     …
     codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId, …);
   }

   @Override
   void onOutputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int outputBufferId, …) {
     ByteBuffer outputBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffer(outputBufferId);
     MediaFormat bufferFormat = codec.getOutputFormat(outputBufferId); // option A
     // bufferFormat is equivalent to mOutputFormat
     // outputBuffer is ready to be processed or rendered.
     …
     codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferId, …);
   }

   @Override
   void onOutputFormatChanged(MediaCodec mc, MediaFormat format) {
     // Subsequent data will conform to new format.
     // Can ignore if using getOutputFormat(outputBufferId)
     mOutputFormat = format; // option B
   }

   @Override
   void onError(…) {
     …
   }
 });
 codec.configure(format, …);
 mOutputFormat = codec.getOutputFormat(); // option B
 codec.start();
 // wait for processing to complete
 codec.stop();
 codec.release();
```

I am unable to relate the code given on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec . Please help

Comment: I hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46405261/192373) can help.

Comment: Are you looking for a real-time solution or an off-line solution?

Comment: realtime solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to create a [Queue](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Queue), push your image's buffer created from **Image** planes into the Queue and process it in the `void onInputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int inputBufferId)`

1) **Create a class to wrap the buffer data :**

```
class MyData{
    byte[] buffer;
    long presentationTimeUs;
    // to tell your encoder that is a EOS, otherwise you can not know when to stop
    boolean isEOS; 
    public MyData(byte[] buffer,long presentationTimeUs, boolean isEOS){
        this.buffer = new byte[buffer.length];
        System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, this.buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        this.presentationTimeUs = presentationTimeUs;
        this.isEOS = isEOS;
    }

    public byte[] getBuffer() {
        return buffer;
    }

    public void setBuffer(byte[] buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    public long getPresentationTimeUs() {
        return presentationTimeUs;
    }

    public void setPresentationTimeUs(long presentationTimeUs) {
        this.presentationTimeUs = presentationTimeUs;
    }

    public boolean isEOS() {
        return isEOS;
    }

    public void setEOS(boolean EOS) {
        isEOS = EOS;
    }

}
```

---

2) **Create the Queue:**

```
Queue<MyData> mQueue = new LinkedList<MyData>();
```

---

3) **Convert Image Planes to byte Array (byte[]) using native code:**

- **Adding native support to Gradle file:**

  ```
  android{

  compileSdkVersion 27

  defaultConfig {
      ...

      externalNativeBuild {
          cmake {
              arguments "-DANDROID_STL=stlport_static"
              cppFlags "-std=c++11"
          }
      }
  }

  externalNativeBuild {
      cmake {
          path "CMakeLists.txt"
      }
  }
  ...
  }
  ```

  - **Creating a function to convert image planes to byte array:**

*(native-yuv-to-buffer.cpp)*

```
    extern "C" JNIEXPORT 
    jbyteArray JNICALL

Java_labs_farzi_camera2previewstream_MainActivity_yuvToBuffer
(

    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject instance,
    jobject yPlane,
    jobject uPlane,
    jobject vPlane,
    jint yPixelStride,
    jint yRowStride,
    jint uPixelStride,
    jint uRowStride,
    jint vPixelStride,
    jint vRowStride,
    jint imgWidth,
    jint imgHeight) {

        bbuf_yIn = static_cast<uint8_t *>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(yPlane));
        bbuf_uIn = static_cast<uint8_t *>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(uPlane));
        bbuf_vIn = static_cast<uint8_t *>(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(vPlane));

        buf = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * imgWidth * imgHeight +
                                 2 * (imgWidth + 1) / 2 * (imgHeight + 1) / 2);

        bool isNV21;
        if (yPixelStride == 1) {
            // All pixels in a row are contiguous; copy one line at a time.
            for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++)
                memcpy(buf + y * imgWidth, bbuf_yIn + y * yRowStride,
                       static_cast<size_t>(imgWidth));
        } else {
            // Highly improbable, but not disallowed by the API. In this case
            // individual pixels aren't stored consecutively but sparsely with
            // other data inbetween each pixel.
            for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++)
                    buf[y * imgWidth + x] = bbuf_yIn[y * yRowStride + x * yPixelStride];
        }

        uint8_t *chromaBuf = &buf[imgWidth * imgHeight];
        int chromaBufStride = 2 * ((imgWidth + 1) / 2);
        if (uPixelStride == 2 && vPixelStride == 2 &&
            uRowStride == vRowStride && bbuf_vIn == bbuf_uIn + 1) {
            isNV21 = true;
            // The actual cb/cr planes happened to be laid out in
            // exact NV21 form in memory; copy them as is
            for (int y = 0; y < (imgHeight + 1) / 2; y++)
                memcpy(chromaBuf + y * chromaBufStride, bbuf_vIn + y * vRowStride,
                       static_cast<size_t>(chromaBufStride));
        } else if (vPixelStride == 2 && uPixelStride == 2 &&
                   uRowStride == vRowStride && bbuf_vIn == bbuf_uIn + 1) {
            isNV21 = false;
            // The cb/cr planes happened to be laid out in exact NV12 form
            // in memory; if the destination API can use NV12 in addition to
            // NV21 do something similar as above, but using cbPtr instead of crPtr.
            // If not, remove this clause and use the generic code below.
        } else {
            isNV21 = true;
            if (vPixelStride == 1 && uPixelStride == 1) {
                // Continuous cb/cr planes; the input data was I420/YV12 or similar;
                // copy it into NV21 form
                for (int y = 0; y < (imgHeight + 1) / 2; y++) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < (imgWidth + 1) / 2; x++) {
                        chromaBuf[y * chromaBufStride + 2 * x + 0] = bbuf_vIn[y * vRowStride + x];
                        chromaBuf[y * chromaBufStride + 2 * x + 1] = bbuf_uIn[y * uRowStride + x];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Generic data copying into NV21
                for (int y = 0; y < (imgHeight + 1) / 2; y++) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < (imgWidth + 1) / 2; x++) {
                        chromaBuf[y * chromaBufStride + 2 * x + 0] = bbuf_vIn[y * vRowStride +
                                                                              x * uPixelStride];
                        chromaBuf[y * chromaBufStride + 2 * x + 1] = bbuf_uIn[y * uRowStride +
                                                                              x * vPixelStride];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        uint8_t *I420Buff = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * imgWidth * imgHeight +
                                               2 * (imgWidth + 1) / 2 * (imgHeight + 1) / 2);
        SPtoI420(buf,I420Buff,imgWidth,imgHeight,isNV21);

        jbyteArray ret = env->NewByteArray(imgWidth * imgHeight *
                                           3/2);
        env->SetByteArrayRegion (ret, 0, imgWidth * imgHeight *
                                         3/2, (jbyte*)I420Buff);
        free(buf);
        free (I420Buff);
        return ret;
    }

- **Adding a function to convert Semi-planar to planar :** 

    bool SPtoI420(const uint8_t *src, uint8_t *dst, int width, int height, bool isNV21)
    {
        if (!src || !dst) {
            return false;
        }

        unsigned int YSize = width * height;
        unsigned int UVSize = (YSize>>1);

        // NV21: Y..Y + VUV...U
        const uint8_t *pSrcY = src;
        const uint8_t *pSrcUV = src + YSize;

        // I420: Y..Y + U.U + V.V
        uint8_t *pDstY = dst;
        uint8_t *pDstU = dst + YSize;
        uint8_t *pDstV = dst + YSize + (UVSize>>1);

        // copy Y
        memcpy(pDstY, pSrcY, YSize);

        // copy U and V
        for (int k=0; k < (UVSize>>1); k++) {
            if(isNV21) {
                pDstV[k] = pSrcUV[k * 2];     // copy V
                pDstU[k] = pSrcUV[k * 2 + 1];   // copy U
            }else{
                pDstU[k] = pSrcUV[k * 2];     // copy V
                pDstV[k] = pSrcUV[k * 2 + 1];   // copy U
            }
        }

        return true;}
```

---

4) **Push your buffer to the queue :**

```
    private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnGetPreviewListener
        = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
        if (image == null)
            return;
        final Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
        Image.Plane yPlane = planes[0];
        Image.Plane uPlane = planes[1];
        Image.Plane vPlane = planes[2];
        byte[] mBuffer = yuvToBuffer(yPlane.getBuffer(),
                uPlane.getBuffer(),
                vPlane.getBuffer(),
                yPlane.getPixelStride(),
                yPlane.getRowStride(),
                uPlane.getPixelStride(),
                uPlane.getRowStride(),
                vPlane.getPixelStride(),
                vPlane.getRowStride(),
                image.getWidth(),
                image.getHeight());
        mQueue.add(new MyData(mBuffer, image.getTimestamp(), false));
        image.close();
        Log.d("hehe", "onImageAvailable");
    }
};
```

5) **Encode the data and save a h264 video file (VLC to play it):**

```
        public void onInputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int inputBufferId) {
        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = mc.getInputBuffer(inputBufferId);
        Log.d(TAG, "onInputBufferAvailable: ");
        // fill inputBuffer with valid data
        MyData data = mQueue.poll();
        if (data != null) {
            // check if is EOS and process with EOS flag if is the case
            // else if NOT EOS
            if (inputBuffer != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onInputBufferAvailable: "+data.getBuffer().length);
                inputBuffer.clear();
                inputBuffer.put(data.getBuffer());

                mc.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId,
                        0,
                        data.getBuffer().length,
                        data.getPresentationTimeUs(),
                        0);
            }

        } else {

            mc.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferId,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOutputBufferAvailable(@NonNull MediaCodec codec, int index, @NonNull MediaCodec.BufferInfo info) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onOutputBufferAvailable: ");
        ByteBuffer outputBuffer = codec.getOutputBuffer(index);
        byte[] outData = new byte[info.size];
        if (outputBuffer != null) {
            outputBuffer.get(outData);
            try {
                fos.write(outData);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        codec.releaseOutputBuffer(index,false);
    }
```

6) **Mux your track** in the `void onOutputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec mc, int outputBufferId, …)` , the processing is similar to the examples with synchronous mode that you can find on the Internet.

I hope my answer will help you

[Full example code here](https://github.com/ximisoft/Camera2PreviewStreamMediaCodecVideoRecording)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Evaluating it before the bounty ends

Comment: I tried the following code but its crashing with some error. Pushed the code here https://github.com/get2abhi/Camera2PreviewStreamMediaCodecVideoRecording .           java.lang.NullPointerException: dst == null
                                                                                     at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
                                                                                     at labs.farzi.camera2previewstream.MyData.<init>(MyData.java:13)

Comment: @HimalayanCoder Sorry I forgot to allocate the byte array, Answer updated (MyData class) can you try?

Comment: Now the next error is [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers (output) failed w/ err -1010. I have pushed the code

Comment: It seems like a codec error on some devices. Apparently, it is harmless you can ignore this error, see Q12 at https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#q12

Comment: Ok but seems like MediaCodec onInputBufferAvailable is no more called. Can you help me with the final code ?

Comment: Ok, I download your code and will make a puu request on github

Comment: Appreciate that. I have been searching a lot for this but seems like no one cared to give a example using mediacodec callbacks. You are my hero

Comment: You are welcome. I created a pull request to your repos, dont hesitate if you have trouble with muxing

Comment: Yep, I merged. Got a blank text.h264 file. Also I receiveed OutputbufferOutofFlow Exception. Need some debugging.

Comment: Make sure that you have the same ImageReader's Image width & height and the encoder width & height

Comment: java.nio.BufferOverflowException
                                                                                     at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:264)
                                                                                     at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:642)
                                                                                     at labs.farzi.camera2previewstream.MainActivity$4.onInputBufferAvailable(MainActivity.java:267

Comment: Worked after changing the dimension. I was using MINIMUM_PREVIEW_SIZE = 320 which led to 480x320 image from camera. Changed width and height and it worked like a charm. Thanks for all your help. Will push my changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180621/discussion-between-himalayancoder-and-e-abdel).

Comment: Nice, the code have to be optimized To handle dimensions automatically, will do some optimisation when I have some time, happy coding

Comment: MediaCodec onInputBufferAvailable initially appeared for around 10 times but it is no more called after onImageAvailable is received. Do I need to add any thread or fix. @HimalayanCoder can you push your changes

Comment: it only appears after you close the previous image. Make sure your image.close() is called. You might have missed in some if elss, try , catch

Comment: its working great on Pixel, galaxy Note 10 but on S8 I see color mismatch. On three phones the log says "ypixel stride 1", "generic data copying". yvu pixelstrides are 1 2 2 row strides are 320 320 320 widthxheight: 320x240 . U and V buffer address are same.

Comment: I download your code, but got error `void java.io.FileOutputStream.write(byte[]) on a null object`. It seems the `fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+"text.h264");` return null.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try out this sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video

I think it will definitely fulfill all of your requirements and you can always reach out to me if you're unable to relate to the code in the sample mentioned above.

**This sample uses the Camera2 API as well as what you want is the conversion from raw YUV frames, which can be done using it. So, I hope that you wont have any issues or problems if you would go through the given sample once and use its code for recording MP4 videos in your desired app.**

**For instance -**
**a)** In this, you will have to implement a [CameraDevice.StateCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.StateCallback) to receive events about changes of the state of the camera device. Override its methods to set your CameraDevice instance, start the preview, and stop and release the camera.

**b)** When starting the preview, set up the **MediaRecorder** to accept video format.

**c)** Then, set up a [CaptureRequest.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.Builder) using createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD) on your CameraDevice instance.

**d)** Then, implement a [CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback), using the method createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){}) on your CameraDevice instance, where surfaces is a list consisting of the surface view of your TextureView and the surface of your **MediaRecorder** instance.

**e)** Use start() and stop() methods on your **MediaRecorder** instance to actually start and stop the recording.

**f)** Lastly, set up and clean up your camera device in onResume() and onPause().

Happy coding.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20912702)

Comment: Hello, @Quicklearner. I have improved my answer to some extent. Hope you would like it now to some extent. LOL...

Comment: You should also add some useful parts from the link you mentioned too which describes the answer pretty well

Comment: I feel first let the questioner go through the sample once as that would help him and then I would definitely help him if there would be any issue to him (as mentioned in my answer) - by adding some useful parts.

Comment: Always add links to comments first, If that doesnt help then post a running example/code as an answer , thats how it should be :)

Comment: I have now improved my answer quite a bit and hope that you would like it. ;)

Comment: i appreciate that, keep it up :)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I am looking for a MediaCodec callback version. MediaRecorder cannot create a video out of individual frame in queue